# How to Filter data from Database using Spring ACL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, acl

I have some data in the db 
And users are given Explicit read permissions on them usin Spring ACL
Does Spring have any standard way of Filtering the data ?

Comment: To filter data you can use Hibernate/JPA but I dont understand the relationship betwween Spring ACL and filtering data.

Comment: I am talking about filtering data based on ACL entries(spring-acl)

Comment: we need to use PreFilter or PostFilter
here is how to [configure it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28647921/how-postfilter-and-prefilter-work)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you already solved it, but I've just found a implementation [here](https://github.com/lordlothar99/strategy-spring-security-acl).

It seems that it could be easily installed on an existing Spring project.